# Getting the value of an element in XML in Clojure?

Tags: xml, clojure

What is the easiest way to get the value of an element from an XML string in Clojure? I am looking for something like:

```
(get-value "<a><b>SOMETHING</b></a>)" "b")
```

to return

```
"SOMETHING"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
user=> (use 'clojure.xml)

user=> (for [x (xml-seq 
          (parse (java.io.File. file)))
             :when (= :b (:tag x))]
     (first (:content x)))
```

Check this [link](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/clojure_xml_parsing_xml-seq) for more info.

Answer (score 10):

Zippers can be handy for xml, they give you xpath like syntax that you can mix with native clojure functions.

```
user=> (require '[clojure zip xml] '[clojure.contrib.zip-filter [xml :as x]])

user=> (def z (-> (.getBytes "<a><b>SOMETHING</b></a>") 
                  java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. 
                  clojure.xml/parse clojure.zip/xml-zip))

user=> (x/xml1-> z :b x/text)
```

returns

```
"SOMETHING"
```

Comment: I would suggest this as best approach as it is not only more functional but also more easy to extend once you get hang of it.. so +1 for Zipper

Answer (score 7):

I do not know how idiomatic Clojure it is but if you happen to know and like [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) it can be used quite easily in Clojure due to its excellent [interoperability with Java](http://clojure.org/java_interop):

```
(import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory) 
(import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory)

(defn document [filename]
  (-> (DocumentBuilderFactory/newInstance)
      .newDocumentBuilder
      (.parse filename)))

(defn get-value [document xpath]
  (-> (XPathFactory/newInstance)
      .newXPath
      (.compile xpath)
      (.evaluate document)))

user=> (get-value (document "something.xml") "//a/b/text()")
"SOMETHING"
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Christophe Grand's great Enlive library:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(map html/text
     (html/select (html/html-snippet "<a><b>SOMETHING</b></a>")  [:a :b]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using clj-xpath, ( https://github.com/brehaut/necessary-evil ) :

```
(use 'com.github.kyleburton.clj-xpath :only [$x:text])
($x:text "/a/b" "<a><b>SOMETHING</b></a>)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this: [Clojure XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194044/clojure-xml-parsing) not what you want? 
An alternative (external) source is here: http://blog.rguha.net/?p=510 .