# clojure xml filtering/searching with data.zip always returns empty

Tags: xml, clojure

Im new to clojure and need to parse some XML. [Other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469971/parsing-xml-in-clojure/6471118) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537923/searching-xml-in-clojure) pointed me to [data.zip](https://github.com/clojure/data.zip) (though most still point to the old clojure-contrib.zip). All I want to do is collect a set of tags, the equivalent of `//Foo`. However, while I can parse the xml all my matches turn up empty.

Out of ideas, I decided to copy a [part of the test code from data.zip](https://github.com/clojure/data.zip/blob/master/src/test/clojure/clojure/data/zip/xml_test.clj) into a standalone clj file. Surely that should work:

```
(ns test.xmltest
  (:require [clojure.xml :as xml]
            [clojure.zip :as zip]
            )
  (:use clojure.pprint)
  (:use clojure.data.zip.xml)

)

(defn parse-str [s]
    (zip/xml-zip (xml/parse (new org.xml.sax.InputSource
                            (new java.io.StringReader s)))))

(def atom1 (parse-str "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                      <feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
                        <id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-28403206</id>
                        <updated>2008-02-14T08:00:58.567-08:00</updated>
                        <title type='text'>n01senet</title>
                        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://n01senet.blogspot.com/'/>
                        <entry>
                          <id>1</id>
                          <published>2008-02-13</published>
                          <title type='text'>clojure is the best lisp yet</title>
                          <author><name>Chouser</name></author>
                        </entry>
                        <entry>
                          <id>2</id>
                          <published>2008-02-07</published>
                          <title type='text'>experimenting with vnc</title>
                          <author><name>agriffis</name></author>
                        </entry>
                      </feed>
                      "))

(defn -main []
  (pprint atom1)
  (xml-> atom1 :title :text)
)
```

However, while the pretty print output looks fine, the actual match result is always `()`, no matter what I put. However, I dont see the difference with this code and the code [in the test file (line 42)](https://github.com/clojure/data.zip/blob/master/src/test/clojure/clojure/data/zip/xml_test.clj). But I must be missing something.

Im running clojure 1.4, leiningen 2, shouldnt be doing anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized the problem. Very silly typo, last line should be `text`, not `:text`.